# Doing a post request via url in Slim Framework

Tags: php, slim

I'm trying to make a `post`request in slim, my intention is inserting data into a mysql database. It's the first time I try to do this, so sorry if I don't explain myself well.

Here's what I have:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require "classes/Autoloader.php";

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->post('/', function(Request $request, Response $response) use ($app) {

    $postVars = $request->getParsedBody();
    $id = $request->getAttribute('id');
    $steps = $request->getAttribute('steps');
    $date = $request->getAttribute('date');

    echo $id . $steps . $date;

    require_once "classes/Connection.php";
    $userdata = new Insert($dbh, $id, $steps, $date);
    $userdata->insert();
});
$app->run();
```

My intention is getting the values, and using them to insert the data, but I keep getting Slim's "Page Not Found" error. This is the url I'm trying with: `http://localhost/wp-api/?id=1&steps=12&date=8787`.

What am I doing wrong, or is this the correct way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Following Justal's answer, I changed my code, on line 10; `$app->post('/'...` specifically. I now get `Method not allowed. Must be one of: POST`

**Edit2:** I changed line 12 (`getQueryParams` -> `getParsedBody`) , and used Postman, otherwise broswer does a `get`request (source of the previous error). It now inserts `null` values into the database, though.

Comment: Your url should be `localhost/1/12/8787`

Comment: @Justinas `wp-api` is the folder it is in!

Answer (score 0):

page not found because you are requesting get on a post route.try below code.

All Data pass in the $request object.

```
$app->post('/', function(Request $request, Response $response) {

echo "<pre>";
print_r($request);
exit;    

});
```

Comment: It works! I had to change `getQueryParams` for `getParsedBody`. It now inserts "null" values into the database, though.

Comment: can you check $request get posted form data?

Comment: Sorry, how do I do that?

Comment: [Here's a link](https://pastebin.com/zThAsYez). I noticed I get an error in Postman that says "Named entity expected. Got none". I don't know what it means.

Comment: okay. your form data not passed in request. can you pls. explain how to call this post request.